# how to assign vector to a subset of a column of a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe. Suppose it has 15 rows.
I want to assign a vector with length 12 to the rows 1 to 12 of one of its columns. How to do that?

```
month <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
DF <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 1.2, 1.4, 1.5, 0.6, 0.4, 1, 0.4, 0.8, 1.3)

b <- c(1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1)

df <- data.frame(DF)
df['cum_pd'] <- NA
df['marg_pd'] <- NA
rownames(df) <- month
df[1:12, "cum_pd"] <- b   # This part is my question
```

Comment: If the frame has 15 rows, assigning 12 values to a column defeats the definition of a frame. The premise of a frame is that each row represents data that is correlated together, sometimes an "observation" (in a study). Please list what your expected output would be, and which of the rows would (arbitrarily?) not get a value. (BTW, "not get a value" in R likely means get an `NA` value, but what you put in there depends also on what you're planning on doing with that data.)

Comment: It looks like that last line does exactly what you want. Please show the output you get and what is unsatisfactory about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty contrived but this will work for arbitrary lengths of `df` and `b` assuming you're always setting the first `n` rows where `n = len(b)`.

`df$cum_pd <- c(b, rep(NA, nrow(df) - length(b)))`

That said, this type of data editing is dubious code at best.

Comment: +1 to the "dubious code at best"; my issue (I believe you agree) is with the misunderstanding of the intent of frames, and the strong potential for mis-analysis because of this

Comment: Yep, and just in practice writing code that alters the same variable line by line but expects sequential execution is a great recipe for disaster in an environment where arbitrary non-sequential execution is one of the major draws. So easy to lose track of your environment.

Comment: +1 that this is generally a bad practice... but with that warning it's still an appropriate question for SO and reasonable to help with the technical aspect of it provided it's used with caution in the right context (e.g. manually correcting mis-entered data).